# Setting error enabled to false on TextInputlayout not removing extra space in Android 9.0

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-textinputlayout

I am using basic `TextInputLayout`. I am setting error when `EditText` is empty. When user enters some text, I am removing error text like this.

```
 tilPassword.isErrorEnabled = false
 tilPassword.error = null
```

This is working fine and good. The reason for calling `tilPassword.isErrorEnabled = false` is that it is helping me to remove extra space that `TextInputLayout` adds to the layout when showing error texts. When user enters some text, I am removing error and also the extra space (that is added by `TextInputLayout`) as well.

Error message is being removed but extra space is not getting removed in Android 9.0. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the error to `""` first/instead of `null`?

Comment: @Blundell I have just tried. Did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#setErrorEnabled(boolean)

The docs explain:

> Enabling this functionality before setting an error message via setError(CharSequence), will mean that this layout will not change size when an error is displayed.

So it would work like so.

Show an error:

```
tilPassword.setErrorEnabled(true)
tilPassword.setError("Wrong password")
```

Hide an error:

```
tilPassword.setError("")
tilPassword.setErrorEnabled(false)
```

Ensure that you are using the AndroidX version of TextInputLayout:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html

As the platform version below is deprecated:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout

Ref. someone explaining the source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35162822/413127

Comment: Yes I have tried exactly like this. Unfortunately, not working. I created a sample project just to check this functionality and, to my surpise, it is working on the sample project. I am trying to further investigate what might also be affecting this behavior. I will update my question after some time.

Comment: Also, I am using `androidx` version of the `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Hi, did investigation for the last couple of hours. I think the problem is with something else. I created a sperate question. Could you please check it out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968915/transition-in-motionlayout-causing-textinputlayout-seterror-message-not-work-in