# Transition in MotionLayout causing TextInputLayout setError message not work in Android 9

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-motionlayout

I have created a sample project on [github](https://github.com/AzizKholmatov/MotionLayout_with_TextInputLayout) Please check it out to reproduce the problem I am facing.

Project Structure: I have basic `TabLayout` and `Viewpager` in `MainActivity`. I also have `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` which are hosted by my `TabLayout`. Everything fairly simple and straightforward there. Look at the screenshots:

[image] [image]

Layout of `MainActivity` has `MotionLayout` as the root layout. When user moves from `FirstFragment` to `SecondFragment`, I increase the size of the `CardView`. My transition code in `transition.xml`:

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:duration="200"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start">
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

As you can see in the screenshots, `SecondFragment` has `TextInputLayout` and a continue `Button`. When `Button` is pressed, I check if the `EditText` is empty or not. If so, I set error message to `TextInputLayout`. When user enters some text and tries to continue again, I remove the error message from `TextInputLayout`. **But, problem is that the extra space (that is added by `TextInputLayout`) to show error message is not being removed.**

How I am removing the error message in `MainActivity`:

```
btnSurnameContinue.setOnClickListener {
            if(etSurname.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                tilSurname.isErrorEnabled = true
                tilSurname.error = "Oops empty detected"
            } else {
                tilSurname.error = ""
                tilSurname.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        }
```

I have test and this issue is happening in Android 9 and Android 8. I checked the same issue on Android 5.0 and it worked pretty fine. I think the problem is specific to Android 9 and Android 8. I have not tested in other versions though.

**IMPORTANT NOTE 1:** If I remove `app:layoutDescription="@xml/transition"` from the `MotionLayout` in `activity_main.xml`, everything is working fine! But removing this means that there will be no animation. What is the point of using `MotionLayout` then?

**IMPORTANT NOTE 2:** After the issue happens, if I swipe to `FirstFragment` and come back to `SecondFragment`, everything starts to work fine. The extra space (which was added because of the error message) will also disappear. Also, error messages (which did not appear at first) starts to appear again (see Additional Problems 2 and 3). It is very strange. I am thinking this swipe back to `FirstFragment` and returning to `SecondFragment` back is causing the `SecondFragment` to re-render itself. Therefore, I am guessing everything starts to work/look correctly. What do you think? May be I am wrong here.

The problem gets even worse when you have mutiple `TextInputLayout`s in the `SecondFragment`. (I have only included one `TextInputLayout` for simplicity in the sample project). So the problems are:

**Additional Problems:**

1. When error is removed, the extra space added to show error is not dissappearing. (This is the main issue that I have explained above).
2. Sometimes, error messages are not even being shown. `TextInputLayout` is colored with accent color only and no error message shown at all.
3. Resetting error message to some other lengthier message causes the error message to be shown partially. Full error message will never be shown.

Please, checkout the [github](https://github.com/AzizKholmatov/MotionLayout_with_TextInputLayout) sample project.

Comment: sorry I don't have the experience with MotionLayout to answer. What I do know is if you have created a reproducable test project in its simplest form, then its potentially a bug with MotionLayout and you should file a bug to Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=323867&template=1023345

Comment: @Blundell Ok. I will report it then. Thank you anyways for your time!